# Custom Module Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object

Tags: magento-1.8, configuration, fatal-error, system.xml

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object in /home/myName/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php on line 463
```

I've looked at numerous sites and StackExchange threads with the same error and I still can't figure out why the error is being thrown.

I'm using a customized extension for tracking customers. Having the entire system.xml file on the server throws the error on my entire System Configuration page.

After commenting out different parts, I've narrowed the error down to having to do with the following bit from the system.xml (the source_model):

```
<fields>
<tipe translate="label">
   <label>Tracking Type</label>
   <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
   <source_model>pixel/system_config_source_tracktype</source_model>
   <sort_order>1</sort_order>
   <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
   <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
   <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</tipe>
</fields>
```

What I have for models within my config.xml:

```
<models>
     <pixel>
         <class>PixelMarket_Pixel_Model</class>
         <resourceModel>pixel_system</resourceModel>
     </pixel>

     <pixel>
         <class>PixelMarket_Pixel_Model</class>
         <resourceModel>pixel_mysql4</resourceModel>
     </pixel>       

     <pixel_mysql4>
          <class>PixelMarket_Pixel_Model_Mysql4</class>
                 <entities>
                        <reftable>
                                <table>reftable</table>
                        </reftable>
                  </entities>
      </pixel_mysql4>

</models>
```

My class within Tracktype.php is:

```
<?php
 class PixelMarket_Pixel_Model_System_Config_Source_Tracktype

{

public function toOptionArray()
{
    $tmp[] = array(
                'value' => '',
                    'label'=> ''
            );
    $tmp[] = array(
                'value' => 1,
                    'label'=> 'Full Tracking'
            );

    $tmp[] = array(
                'value' => 2,
                    'label'=> 'External Referrer Tracking Only'
            );

    return $tmp;
}

}
```

Path of Tracktype.php same as class.

Comment: `Path of Tracktype.php same as class` - sorry if this seems trivial, but can you please show the exact path to that class, including the actual filename itself.

Comment: I probably worded that awkwardly. The path of Tracktype.php is `app/code/local/PixelMarket/Pixel/Model/System/Config/Source/Tracktype.php`

Comment: First step - remove the first `<pixel>` model definition. It shouldn't matter, because the second one will overload it, but remove it anyway just to rule it out. Second step - install n98-magerun if you haven't already and test the model alias resolution `n98-magerun.phar dev:class:lookup model pixel/system_config_source_tracktype`

Comment: Forgive me, unfortunately, I'm still a Magento novice and I'm not familiar with Linux. So the installation page is a bit unclear to me.